# Удаление всех объектов с Realm, кроме некоторых объектов

Tags: android, база-данных, realm

Как можно очистить все объекты с Realm, кроме некоторых. 
Например у нас есть Класс (Objects.class) в котором есть: Users, Pets, Dragons, Retards. И я хочу очистить всё, кроме Retards. 
P.S. конечно Объекты другие и их намного больше и хотел узнать как можно отчистить всё, кроме одного.
P.P.S. У меня есть свой тупой метод чистить каждый класс с базы по отдельности, но это затратно.

Заранее спасибо тому, кто поможет.

Comment: У БД запрашиваете кол-во классов, делаете цикл по длине.
Обычная логика, если имя класса Retards, то тело не срабатывает, не очищаете.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете выборку в **RealmResults** тех объектов, которые хотите удалить и удаляете. Условия выборки можно задать любые. Только не забывайте, что само удаление должно происходить внутри транзакции.

```
RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();
results.deleteAllFromRealm();
```